# Can I Respond to all dns requests with a specific cname?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, unbound

Is is it possible to configure a dns server (dnsmasq, unbound etc. i dont really care which one) to respond to all request with a specific cname, except for the cname itself? And if yes how and with which server?

Comment: Look at bind RPZ feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any of them, but you are spoofing the entire DNS structure at this point, which means that you'll need to do the TLD, etc. for what you want to actually work.  Of course, it may be easier to just spoof all of it to point to whatever the CNAME is supposed to resolve to with an A record and skip the whole CNAME business altogether.

Also, instead of breaking DNS completely, have you considered a firewall solution that simply re-routes all the traffic to your desired destination?